# Typing filename in ListBox

Tags: vb.net, listbox

when I wish to type the name of a listbox item (the listbox is populated by files in a directory), for example, if I type "apples" pressing A would take me to the first object with A in it's name, but typing "p" after will take me to the first item with p as the first letter. Is there any way I can make it so I can type a few characters and it would take me to that specific item? For example, the list might have;

```
 ability
 idea
 boring
```

typing "abi" would select ability, rather than "ability", then "boring", then "idea"

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's possible to make System.Windows.Forms.ListBox behave like that, but it would take some non-trivial code to make it work.  System.Windows.Forms.ListView has this behavior built-in, so I would suggest using a ListView instead of a ListBox.

```
' Hide the headers to make the ListView look like a ListBox.
Me.ListView1.View = View.Details
Me.ListView1.HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.None

Me.ListView1.BeginUpdate()
Try
  ' System.Windows.Forms.ListView doesn't have data binding capability.
  ' The listview's items have to be added using its
  ' Items.Add, Items.AddRange or Items.Insert methods.
  For Each filename As String In Directory.GetFiles("C:\Windows").Select(Function(s) Path.GetFileName(s))
    Me.ListView1.Items.Add(filename)
  Next
Finally
  Me.ListView1.EndUpdate()
End Try

' Add the column after adding the items.
' Setting column width to -1 will make
' the column autosize itself to the longest item.
Dim columnHeader As New ColumnHeader
columnHeader.Width = -1
Me.ListView1.Columns.Add(columnHeader)
```

Comment: How do you give someone rep? Because your code worked like a charm! Thank you so much, I've been at this forever now. :D

Comment: @Matt: Here's the FAQ entry on rep (http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation).  You gave me points when you accepted the answer.  Thank you!